# j2me: Error opening stream - "java.io.IOException: -7334"

Tags: http, exception, java-me, header

I am making HTTP connections to server to get some data. It works on most devices, but
I'm getting this error on Sony Ericsson P1i.

I have found error description:

```
KErrHttpInvalidHeaderInRequest   -7334
Request contained a response header or a entity header but no body
```

Body should exists, I mean, data is not zero-length, and other devices with the same SIM-card and internet settings could get it in.

Comment: try logging the request and post it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it!

The problem was in request properties. I remove all these methods:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("...", "...");
```

and it works :)

Comment: I've the same problem. I'm trying to read an audio streaming for blackberry and it gives me an error opening the streaming. I've comment all the connection.setRequestProperty...but nothing changes